# Too little root space

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, disk-usage

I'm completly confused. Per accident more or less I gave my PC 100 GB for root. And now Ubuntu tells me I am out of space, 0 byte left. I cleared the trash to get a little bit to work with (5GB), still tells me zero bytes left, allthoug I managed to mount my backup drive. And I read people are using 30 GB and less for root. I am using SystemBack to avoid long installation time and to get the system I am used to. I partitioned as followed:

- GPT Partion table
- `/` 100GB
- Boot/Efi 200MB
- SWAP 6GB
- Home rest  ~2TB

I installed around 2 weeks ago, and root is full. If I knew how to search for big files or folders, would be a great help.
edit is what I am looking for

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G  4,0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3,2G  1,9M  3,2G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       116G  116G     0 100% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G  360K   16G   1% /run/shm<br<
none            100M   72K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda4       2,5T  282G  2,1T  12% /home
/dev/sda2       197M  3,4M  194M   2% /boot/efi
overflow        1,0M  8,0K 1016K   1% /tmp
/dev/sdc1       3,7G  2,5G  1,2G  69% /media/dag/SBLIVE


$ df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             4,0M   606  4,0M    1% /dev
tmpfs            4,0M   786  4,0M    1% /run
/dev/sda1        7,4M  451K  6,9M    7% /
none             4,0M     2  4,0M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             4,0M     5  4,0M    1% /run/lock
none             4,0M    17  4,0M    1% /run/shm
none             4,0M    30  4,0M    1% /run/user
/dev/sda4        161M  652K  161M    1% /home
/dev/sda2           0     0     0     - /boot/efi
overflow         4,0M    13  4,0M    1% /tmp
/dev/sdc1           0     0     0     - /media/dag/SBLIVE

$ sudo du -axBM -d 1 / | sort -nr | head -20
118010M /
110164M /media
5377M   /usr
1378M   /lib
728M    /var
324M    /boot
15M /etc
13M /sbin
10M /bin
4M  /opt
1M  /srv
1M  /root
1M  /mnt
1M  /lost+found
1M  /lib64
1M  /core
1M  /cdrom
0M  /vmlinuz.old
0M  /vmlinuz
0M  /initrd.img.old
```

Comment: The command `sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20` will show you the largest twenty files / subdirectories of your current directory.  The first time you run it, it takes a while as it reads the directory structure.

Comment: 2949908M .
2652751M ./media
289307M ./home
5377M ./usr
1378M ./lib
728M ./var
327M ./boot
15M ./etc
13M ./sbin
10M ./bin
4M ./opt
3M ./run
1M ./tmp
1M ./srv
1M ./root
1M ./mnt
1M ./lost+found
1M ./lib64
1M ./dev

Comment: To me it looks as if it definitely shouldn't use 100GB. Could you please post the output of `df -h | grep "/$"`? (It should show how much space is left on the root partition - just in case the notice you get is somehow bugged...)

(Edit: Or you could try  `df -h | egrep "(/$|File)"` which results in the same but with the header)

Comment: maybe inode issue...

Comment: It would help to see the mount points, and a modification to the directory sort I posted earlier would help.  Please run `df -h`, `df -ih` and `sudo du -axBM -d 1 / | sort -nr | head -20` and append the outputs of these commands into your question, rather then into a comment.

Comment: dag@CD01:~$ df -h | egrep "(/$|File)"
/dev/sda1       116G    116G     0  100% /

Comment: can I place the results elsewhere? too long for the outpust here

Comment: And I have german, must switch to english

Comment: If the output is too long to be added to your question (is there a limit?) you could maybe put it on pastebin.

I'm pretty sure that there's no need to change the language, most of the text is in the headers in the first line of the output anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: Looks like /media is the culprit.

Comment: How many kernels do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu kernels? 1 Agree with /media, looks strange

Comment: looked at one porposal, How do I free up more space in /boot?

Comment: sems I have a lot of linux. funny they doesn't show up at booting time, in that case I would have been aware. I try that

Comment: please look at the original question, as I have added some outputs there. btw. if I delete old linux-kernels in /boot of course will not help at all, I tried one

Comment: I supose it will not help me much to reinstall again with SystemBack. I suppose the error lies in the preinstalled system already. When I install completle new now, can you advice me how much space I can give to every partitio? Also in future I want to use SystemBack, because I can easely install all my PC's (2) and Laptops(4) with one setup. And for that I need 4 partitions

Comment: I thank you all for your support. I installed neew with 30GB root. On the original PC ro0t has stayed stable with 9GB since months